# Concatenate two strings of different lists based on a value

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

I have the following variable `z`:

```py
z =   [
        ['8575748' , 't', 'TextA.\n'],
        ['8575748' , 'a', 'TextB.\n'],
        ['10556298', 't', 'TextC.\n'],
        ['10556298', 'a', 'TextD.\n'],

       ]
```

`'TextA\n'`, `'TextB\n'`, `'TextC\n'`, and `'TextD\n'` are nothing but text samples parsed from `.txt` file. `'t'` and `'a'`stand for `title` and `abstract`, respectively.

I am trying the produce the following output:

```py
[('8575748', 'TextA.' + ' ' + 'TextB.'), ('10556298', 'TextC.' + ' ' + 'TextD.')]
```

That is `title` and `abstract` to be concatenated with space `' '`. Note that there is `\n` at the end of each text which is subject to be removed during concatenating.

I tried the following:

```py
(list(zip(z[0], z[1]))[0][0] , \
 list(zip(z[0], z[1]))[2][0].strip('\n') + list(zip(z[0], z[1]))[2][1].strip('\n'))
```

Which looks long code. I want to have a fast and clean code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
z = [
    ["8575748", "t", "TextA.\n"],
    ["8575748", "a", "TextB.\n"],
    ["10556298", "t", "TextC.\n"],
    ["10556298", "a", "TextD.\n"],
]

out = {}
for id_, _, txt in z:
    out.setdefault(id_, []).append(txt.strip())

out = [(k, " ".join(v)) for k, v in out.items()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[('8575748', 'TextA. TextB.'), ('10556298', 'TextC. TextD.')]
```

Comment: I tried to implement this code with a large list. I got a traceback in **for loop**: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

Comment: @Joe Does your list always contain 3 values? It seems that some items have only 2